# android hide status bar synchronously

Tags: java, android

I need to put the device programmatically in full screen mode to animate a view, zooming it. I have done that, but i would like to start my animation only after my status bar completely be hidden on device. How can i do it synchronously? WhatsApp do it in android with the profile picture.

My code the hidden status bar:

```
        //Hide toolbar and set full screen mode
    View decorView = context.getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
    ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(context);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait 2 sec for hide actionBar

```
// time delay to hide actionBar
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new

Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        startAnimate();
    }
}

,2000); // e.g. 2000 milliseconds
```